# PCF - x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: cloud-foundry, x509certificate, pcfdev

I am trying to setup pcf in Ubuntu20. While i am setting up it, its notable to create and found

> x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Here are deploy bash log file as follows. Can someone help me out ?

`deploy-bosh.log`

```
Starting registry... Finished (00:00:00)
Uploading stemcell 'bosh-warden-boshlite-ubuntu-xenial-go_agent/170.16'... Skipped [Stemcell already uploaded] (00:00:00)

Started deploying
  Deleting VM '654e6637-3333-4879-a5a7-26a6066585ab'... Finished (00:00:14)
  Creating VM for instance 'bosh/0' from stemcell '211465a3-381f-4fdd-83ba-9591803442f9'... Finished (00:00:05)
  Waiting for the agent on VM '7091e293-6518-4008-b337-cbbf2d273eae' to be ready... Failed (00:00:04)
Failed deploying (00:00:23)

Stopping registry... Finished (00:00:00)
Cleaning up rendered CPI jobs... Finished (00:00:00)
Deploying:
  Creating instance 'bosh/0':
    Waiting until instance is ready:
      Post https://mbus:<redacted>@10.144.0.2:6868/agent: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
Exit code 1
```

Comment: I got the same issue while installing on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. Unfortunatly the installation process  is poorly documented: https://docs.pivotal.io/pcf-dev/install-linux.html.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, sorry its post late now.